# can we use %rowtype for two tables with join condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

1.dept(parent table)
   -deptno dname loc

2.emp(child table) 
    -empno ename sal deptno

*display ename,loc while we give empno  using %rowtype.

*using this plsql program to achieve result.

```
DECLARE 

   v1 emp%rowtype;

   v2 dept1%rowtype;

   vnum  emp.empno%type:='&no';

BEGIN

  SELECT A.ename,b.loc

  INTO v1,v2

  FROM emp A,dept1 b 

  WHERE A.deptno=b.deptno AND A.empno=vnum;

  dbms_output.put_line(v1.ename||'**'||v2.loc);

end;
```

Comment: No it's not possible. But you can declare cursor from your query and use cursor%rowtype.

Comment: sir cursor may return more rows.....here i return only one row while we give empno from user......so it return one row only

Comment: You can create an explicit cursor that has formal parameters, and then pass different
actual parameters to the cursor each time you open it. In your case you can pass "empno" to your cursor to restrict underline query to give only one record. Suggest you to follow Oracle Documentation

Answer (score 1):

We can define a bespoke record type to match the projection of a specific query in PL/SQL. One advantage of this is the ability to define a table type from the record type, which is handy for fetching multiple records.

```
DECLARE 
   type v_rec_t is record (
      ename emp.ename%type
      , loc dept1.loc%type
      );
   l_rec v_rec_t;

   type v_rec_nt is table of  v_rec_t;
   l_recs v_rec_nt;  

BEGIN

  SELECT A.ename, b.loc
  INTO l_rec
  FROM emp A, dept1 b 
  WHERE A.deptno = b.deptno 
  AND A.empno = &empno;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_rec.ename ||'**'|| l_rec.loc);

  -- get multiple rows
  SELECT A.ename, b.loc
  bulk collect INTO l_recs
  FROM emp A
       join dept1 b 
      on A.deptno = b.deptno 
  where A.deptno = &deptno;


  dbms_output.put_line(' emps in dept'|| l_recs.count());

end;
```

One of the reasons to define explicit cursors is that we can define a record variable based on their projection:

```
declare
    cursor c_emploc (p_empid emp.empno%type) is
         SELECT A.ename, b.loc
         FROM emp A, dept1 b 
         WHERE A.deptno = b.deptno 
         AND A.empno = p_empid;
  r_emploc c_emploc%rowtype;
  ....
```

Comment: @pandiyanram - if you have found this response helpful please upvote or accept it. Accepted answers make StackOverflow a better resource for future Seekers.

Answer (score 0):

Why use rowtype if all you select are single columns? 
You can declare the variables using the column type.

```
DECLARE
v1 emp.ename%type;
v2 dept1.loc%type;
vnum emp.empno%type:='&no';
BEGIN
    SELECT A.ename,
        b.loc
    INTO v1,
        v2
    FROM emp A,
        dept1 b
    WHERE A.deptno=b.deptno
    AND A.empno   =vnum;
    dbms_output.put_line(v1.ename||'**'||v2.loc);
END;
```